# После переноса проекта на другой ПК получаю ошибку ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день, перенес проект с одного ПК на другой, стал получать ошибку при компиляции:

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
```

Если создаю новый проект и переношу все файлы с этого проекта в тот, получаю ту же самую ошибку.

В чем беда?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка `:app:mergeDebugResources` означает провал попытки смёржить (то есть собрать в кучку) ресурсы приложения. Обычно в приложении ресурсы генерируются из нескольких источников (build.gradle, манифест, assets, res и проч.), далее они собираются в один финальный ресурсный файл, который и компилируется. Куски ресурсов собираются в каталоги `build/intermediates` и `build/generated`, далее при *merge* все это собирается в каталог `build/intermediates/*/merged` и `build/intermediates/*/full`

Изучите содержимое этих каталогов и заодно изучите логи gradle которые валятся на `build/outputs/logs` - там посмотрите секцию `merge`

Comment: у меня нету в папке проекта каталога build/outputs/logs, где тогда логи посмотреть?

Comment: Покажите все дерево каталогов проекта